# JSon mismatch between .net and swift 2

Tags: json, swift, asp.net-web-api

I have build an asp.net webapi to export data in json format.
In my ios 9 app (swift 2) I try to load that data but it doesn't work.

I think it has todo with the structure/format of the json data. 
Sample from https://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/newest.json works fine to load in the app.
loans json data starts with:

> {   "paging": {
>       "page": 1,
>       "total": 3699,
>       "page_size": 20,
>       "pages": 185   },
>       "loans": [
>       {
>         "id": 1012426,
>         "name": "Arati",
>         "description": {
>           "languages": [
>             "en"
>           ]
>         },

My json data starts with:

> [   {
>       "id": 5,
>       "name": "Test",
>       "createDate": "2015-04-04T20:28:07",
>       "changeDate": "2015-05-06T15:09:06.18"
>       }, ....continues with more items

In my swift code

> NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:
>        NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)  as? NSDictionary

it find 2 keys (paging and loans) in dictionary for the loan json.
With my json the dictionary ends up with nil.

I clearly see the difference in json format/structure. But how do I get my webapi to export json data similar to:

> { "items": 
>   [   {
>       "id": 5,
>       "name": "Test",
>       "createDate": "2015-04-04T20:28:07",
>       "changeDate": "2015-05-06T15:09:06.18"
>       }, ....continues with more items

In my asp.net code I have an ApiController with the following method:

> public IEnumerable Get() {
>      List list = ....getting data
>      return list
>   }

OR can I in swift read json in another way that works?

Comment: `With my json the dictionary ends up with nil` But *your* JSON is an array, not a dictionary. So on the Swfit side, the cast as NSDictionary fails. Cast as NSArray (or better, a Swift array) instead.

Comment: But of course. I was to fixed with the sample. It worked when Icasted it to an NSArray. Thanks Eric.